# How to solve homestead version in Vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, laravel-8

For a new project we use Laravel 8 and Homestead. This project uses php8. I already have installed VirtualBox, Vagrant and Homestead.
When typing "vagrant up" I keep getting an error message. I've been trying to get it to work for more than 1 day but it doesn't work. Hopefully you can help me with it.

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the [installation guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#installing-homestead)? You shouldn't use the homestead master branch because it is unstable, try using `git checkout release` to use the latest stable release.

Comment: Yes I have followed the guid! What do you mean by "git checkout release"? can you please explain that?

Comment: It is explained in the installation guide, you need to run `git checkout release` to switch to the correct homestead branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are on the `master` branch which is unstable. You need to switch to the `release` branch in order to get the latest stable homestead release.

From the [installation guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#installing-homestead):

> After cloning the Laravel Homestead repository, you should checkout
> the `release` branch. This branch always contains the latest stable
> release of Homestead:

```
cd ~/Homestead

git checkout release
```